# Updating file references in a json file via a grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gruntjs

I'm a JavaScript developer and fairly new to creating a build process from scratch. I chose to use Grunt for my current project and have created a GruntFile that does about 90% of what I need it to do and it works great, except for this one issue. I have several JavaScript files that I reference while I'm developing a chrome extension in the `manifest.json` file. For my build process I am concatenating all of these files and minifying it into one file to be included in `manifest.json`. Is there anyway to update the file references in the `manifest.json` file during the build process so it points to the minified version?

Here is a snippet of the src manifest file:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/lib/zepto.js",
            "js/injection.js",
            "js/plugins/plugin1.js",
            "js/plugins/plugin2.js",
            "js/plugins/plugin3.js",
            "js/injection-init.js"
        ]
    }],
    "version": "2.0",
}
```

I have a grunt task that concatenates and minifies all the js files listed above into one file called `injection.js` and would like a grunt task that can modify the manifest file so it looks like this:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/injection.js"
        ]
    }],
    "version": "2.0",
}
```

What I've done for now is have 2 versions of the manifest file, one for dev and one for build, during the build process it copies the build version instead. This means I need to maintain 2 versions which I'd rather not do. Is there anyway to do this more elegantly with Grunt?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Grunt` gives its own api for reading and writing files, i feel that better than other dependencies like `fs`:
Edit/update json file using grunt with command `grunt updatejson:key:value` after putting this task in your gruntjs file

```
grunt.registerTask('updatejson', function (key, value) {
        var projectFile = "path/to/json/file";


        if (!grunt.file.exists(projectFile)) {
            grunt.log.error("file " + projectFile + " not found");
            return true;//return false to abort the execution
        }
        var project = grunt.file.readJSON(projectFile);//get file as json object

        project[key]= value;//edit the value of json object, you can also use projec.key if you know what you are updating

        grunt.file.write(projectFile, JSON.stringify(project, null, 2));//serialize it back to file

    });
```

Comment: likewise there is `grunt.file.readYAML`, try http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file for info

Comment: Just noticed this comment, thanks that's good to know. I've since started using browserify and that has sort of negated the reason I started this thread in the first place... however I do still read/write files in grunt using fs for other reasons and this is really helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I do something similar - you can load your manifest, update the contents then serialize it out again.  Something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('fixmanifest', function() {
     var tmpPkg = require('./path/to/manifest/manifest.json');

     tmpPkg.foo = "bar";
     fs.writeFileSync('./new/path/to/manifest.json', JSON.stringify(tmpPkg,null,2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other answers here.

1) Why use `grunt.file.write` instead of `fs`? `grunt.file.write` is *just a wrapper for* `fs.writeFilySync` (see code [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/file.js#L282)).

2) Why use `fs.writeFileSync` when grunt makes it *really easy* to do stuff asynchronously? There's no doubt that you don't *need* async in a build process, but if it's easy to do, *why wouldn't you*? (It is, in fact, only a couple characters longer than the `writeFileSync` implementation.)

I'd suggest the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
grunt.registerTask('writeManifest', 'Updates the project manifest', function() {
    var manifest = require('./path/to/manifest'); // .json not necessary with require
    manifest.fileReference = '/new/file/location';
    // Calling this.async() returns an async callback and tells grunt that your
    // task is asynchronous, and that it should wait till the callback is called
    fs.writeFile('./path/to/manifest.json', JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2), this.async());

    // Note that "require" loads files relative to __dirname, while fs
    // is relative to process.cwd(). It's easy to get burned by that.
});
```

Comment: Actually `require()` is synchronous FS so your task isn't actually completely async.

Comment: Well, for one, I didn't say it was. I was just suggesting `fs.writeFile` as an alternative (read: improvement) to `grunt.file.write`. The other solutions also `require` the json file, so this is still an improvement. If you _really_ care about making the entire task async, you can either `fs.readFile` the json manifest or move the require outside the task itself (i.e. where `fs` is required) since the grunt task collection itself is synchronous (that's assuming, of course, that the manifest doesn't change between task load and task run).

Comment: Another improvement I'd suggest pretty much universally with grunt tasks is to use `fs-extra` in place of `fs`, and use methods such as `outputFile`, which will `mkdir -p` any missing directory paths.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad thing. IMHO async vs sync is a preference when it comes to build scripts, they don't need to be lightning fast.

Comment: grunt.file.write looks nicer

Comment: Why? That's just opinion.