# Node.js update JSON data in file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have to write some JSON data on a file. 
Some JSON objects must be update during the execution of the program and these updates must be saved in the file (for example objects in array).

Exist a way to do this without rewrite the entire file?

JSON structure:

```
{
    "varA": {
        "varA1": value,
        "varA2": value,
    },
    "varB": value,
    "varC": value,
    "varD": value,
    "array": [
        { obj1 },
        { obj2 },
        { obj3 },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Doubt it, my impression is that FS writes the whole file or nothing. Why don't you want to rewrite it? Maybe split up your JSON into multiple files and/or store it in data or memory.

Comment: You can [write to arbitrary positions](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) or [append to files](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback) easily, but of course for that you need to know the structure of your file.

Comment: During my test I saw if I turn off the server during the write process then the entire file will be blank, losing all data previously recorded. The simple append can't work because data that should be updated are elements of another object so I will have problems with brackets

Comment: I would use mongo or some other lightweight json db for node.

Comment: @Bergi I've added the structure of JSON in the file.

Comment: @vittore It's a possibility but these are config files that should be moved from a pc to another, I think that is better work with files

Comment: @MaxMarkson: Seems like you want a properly written database, not a simple file.

Comment: If you need to access them from different machines, thats another "pro" for proper db, so you dont need to take care of file sync on your own.

Comment: If you want slightly more sophisticated, I'd create a new file instead of trying to rewrite an existing file (with a new filename), and always look for the newest file when loading/sync'ing the file. Purge the old files when you "find" a newer one.

Comment: Ok, I'll use @WiredPrairie solution. Thank you guys! PS if you write your proposal as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want slightly more sophisticated solution to file management (yet quite simple to implement), I'd:

1. create a new file instead of trying to rewrite an existing file (with a new filename every time). I'd suggest using something that includes a time stamp (either human readable or as milliseconds).
2. and always look for the newest file when loading/sync'ing the file
3. Purge the old files when you "find" a newer one **and** it reads successfully. If the file doesn't read successfully, something has happened. Fall back to the next file, and ideally delete the bad file. Or, just wait until a new file is successfully written.

This way, you don't need to worry about files not being completely written etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one file, I would strongly encourage you to use MongoDB, as it is exactly what it is good for.

With MongoDB you can do things like (from [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)):

```
   db.books.update( { item: "Divine Comedy" },
             {
               $set: { price: 18 }, // set property value
               $inc: { stock: 5 },   // increment etc field value

             } )

   // add value in array
   db.bios.update(
     { _id: 1 },
     {
        $push: { awards: { award: "IBM Fellow", year: 1963, by: "IBM" } }
     }
```

)

UPDATE: Also, since you mentioned that files are in fact configuration, check out what Grunt can do. For instance answer to this question [Updating file references in a json file via a grunt task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052301/updating-file-references-in-a-json-file-via-a-grunt-task)

Comment: From a relatively simple file request to using a Database system? That's a potentially large and complex (and costly) modification to an infrastructure if MongoDB isn't already in use.

Comment: In this weekend I'll study your proposal but at the moment I'm for WiredPrairie's idea.